# Linux server laravel application cannot modify temp folder

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have an application running on my local windows machine (xampp), and it has a feature to upload an excel file, which works fine.

As soon as my application is deployed on a linux server, it will no longer validate the files.

I have done some investigation and I have noticed, no matter what permissions are set or who owns the linux `tmp` directory, my laravel application will not modify the folder.

If i ssh into the folder and run .stat i get

```
Access: 2018-02-02 11:07:58.889993250 +0000
Modify: 2018-01-31 13:23:41.496991422 +0000
Change: 2018-02-02 11:07:37.672993125 +0000
```

When running on my windows machine, the modified date changes also, so i'm thinking that this could be the problem.

Why wont my application modify the linux temp folder, when the owner and permissions are definitely correct?

Comment: Does the `www-data` (or your web servers user:group) user have the right permissions?

Comment: How exactly do you want to modify the system folder `/tmp`? Have you made sure beforehand that your folders in the Laravel `storage` folder are writeable?

Comment: Even if i set the tmp folder permissions to 777 so it is completely writable and modifiable it still doesnt work. And sorry @btl what do you mean? I don't deal with linux servers too much so im not sure what you mean.

Comment: In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` it should have an entry near the top like `user      www-data:www-data` (It may be a different user). That's the user it's running under and the one needing the correct permissions

Comment: The etc folder on the server does not contain an nginx folder?

Comment: Another possibility is you are exceeding the file size limitations for uploading to tmp. If that is the case you'll need to change the upload path in the nginx config, I believe it is the `client_body_temp_path` that must be changed. Ive only ever had to do this once and it was not an obvious solution.  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_temp_path

Comment: If it's not in `etc` look in `/usr/share/nginx/`

Comment: Its definitely not exceeding the file size limitation as the file itself is 30kb.

Comment: Cant find a share folder either

Comment: Does `ps aux | grep nginx` show where it's running out of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164409/discussion-between-s-r-and-btl).